# Server error 500 in Retrofit during POST request

Tags: android, retrofit

I have rest api designed in Slim 3. which stores the customer details in MySQL db. I am using Retrofit 1.9 to connect to webservice. I am receiving server error 500 where as same request working fine in POSTMAN.

```
   //using retrofit
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(Config.CUSTOMER_URL).build();
        RegisterCustomer api = adapter.create(RegisterCustomer.class);
        api.registerCustomer(custName.toString(),
                             phoneNumber.toString(),
                             address.toString(),
                             Config.API_KEY, new Callback<retrofit.client.Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(retrofit.client.Response result, retrofit.client.Response response) {
                        BufferedReader reader = null;
                        String output = "";
                        try {
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));
                            output = reader.readLine();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d("customer result",result.getBody()+"##"+result.getStatus() +"##" +response.getBody().toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        Log.d("customer save fail ",error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

Interface:

```
 public interface RegisterCustomer
{
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/customer")
    public void registerCustomer(
            @Field("cust_name") String cust_name,
            @Field("phone") String phone,
            @Field("address") String address,
            @Field("apikey") String apikey,
            Callback<Response> callback);
}
```

My php code.

```
     // Adding customer 
// pass cust_name,phone,address and apikey
    $app->post('/customer', function ($request, $response, $args) {
                    $_message = $request->getParsedBody();
                    $customer = new Customer();
                    $customer->cust_name = $_message['cust_name'];
                    $customer->phone     = $_message['phone'];
                    $customer->address   = $_message['address'];
                    $customer->apikey    = $_message['apikey'];
                    $payload=[];
                    $customer->save();
                    if ($customer->id) {
                        $payload = ['cust_id'   => $customer->id,
                                    'cust_uri' => '/customer/' . $customer->id
                                    ];
                 return $response->withStatus(201)->withJson($payload);
                    }else {
                        return $response->withStatus(400);
                    }


            });
```

[image]

Comment: post your logcat error please

Comment: 5xx errors are server errors, please add your logcat error here

Comment: your logcat stack trace. please.

Comment: php_error_log:[24-Jan-2017 10:55:06 Europe/Berlin] POST -- http://192.168.0.101/grocery_api/customer

Comment: 01-24 16:00:25.403 7437-7437/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/customer save fail: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I switch to Retrofit 2(Okhttp) which has logging capability, which solves my problem but I am getting null response. The earlier problem was the url, which is not the correct.